# ASP.NET MVC - Static objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a question about static strings and so forth, in an ASP.NET MVC.

I need to hold a string(a value), when the user goes through the application. 
Problem is, I feel like that would be a violation to the MVC. I just need to store a string per user, so it seems like a violation to the MVC separation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just need to store a string per user

You could use [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx) or [Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx) which both guarantee a safe per user storage. Don't use static objects. They will be shared between all users of the application.

Comment: All of the page is just AJAX calls, any ideas how I do that?

Comment: @ReigoHein, do what? Did you read the corresponding articles about Session and Cookies that I have linked to in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

A commonly recognized best practice would be, unless you have specific requirements/restrictions, to use `cookies` to store data that must persist through multiple request (like the string you're talking about, or authentication information, etc) and `session` for things that need to be persisted only from a request to another (like validation data for the PRG pattern and such).

Try to avoid `session` for anything that is not short-lived. I'll not dive into details but you can easily google about this topic and find many detailed explanation of why it is a bad design choice.

Comment: Actually, seems that I could use sessions, as I do need it for a short-lived string. :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, to the people searching, one option is to use HttpContext.Cache(stringname) in the ASP.NET MVC framework, currently trying that way at the moment.